# How to fix the delay error in my Verilog code?

Tags: delay, verilog, fpga

I want to use a delay with `#` symbol, but the code gives error because of it.  If I remove it, then the program works.
Here is the code:

```
module b5(
input wire switch,
output wire led
);

 #100 assign led = switch;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay is in the wrong location. it should be `assign #100 led = switch;`

FYI: `#` delays only work in simulations. If you plan on synthesizing (such as running on FPGA), then you cannot use `#` delay. Use a clocked pipe-line instead.